# Lambda argument should be moved out of parentheses

Tags: kotlin

IntelliJ gives the following complaint:

> Lambda argument should be moved out of parentheses

```
val profile = loadProfiles()
profile.sortedWith(Comparator({ profile1, profile2 ->
                if (profile1.age > profile2.age) return@Comparator 1
                if (profile1.age < profile2.age) return@Comparator -1
                return@Comparator 0
            }))

data class Developer(var age: Int)

fun loadProfiles(): List<Developer> {
    val listOfNumber = listOf<Developer>(Developer(2), Developer(5), Developer(3))

    return listOfNumber
}
```

How should I format the above to get rid of the complaint? Also, the sorting code doesn't sort. What is causing the problem?

Comment: you may also be interested in `profile.sortedBy { it.age }` instead... Note also that it is not sorting the underlying list, but rather returning a new sorted list.

Comment: ... and I meant: `Alt` + `Enter` or click on the light bulb to let Intellij solve that issue for you...

Comment: Initially, I was hesitant to do this, but renaming `it` helps make it feel more natural: `readInput(day = 1) { line -> line.toIntOrNull() }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> sortedWith(): Returns a list of all elements sorted according to the
>   specified [comparator]

So to sort `profile` list you have to assign the list returned by `sortedWith()` to `profile` (also change its declaration from `val` to `var`)

```
var profile = loadProfiles()
profile = profile.sortedWith(Comparator { profile1, profile2 ->
    if (profile1.age > profile2.age) return@Comparator 1
    if (profile1.age < profile2.age) return@Comparator -1
    return@Comparator 0
})

profile.forEach { println(it.age) }
```

or

```
val profile = loadProfiles().sortedWith(Comparator { profile1, profile2 ->
    if (profile1.age > profile2.age) return@Comparator 1
    if (profile1.age < profile2.age) return@Comparator -1
    return@Comparator 0
})
```

For the warning: press Alt+Enter and let InteliJ make the change.

Answer (score 48):

This warning is caused because in Kotlin lambda parameters can (and actually should be) outside parentheses.

See this:

```
fun onClick(action: () -> Unit) { ... }
```

When you use function like this you can use:

```
view.onClick({ toast(it.toString())} )
view.onClick() { toast(it.toString()) }
view.onClick { toast(it.toString()) }
```

All of those forms are correct (compiler will not fail), but in Kotlin Style Guide you'll find following statement:

> If a call takes a single lambda, it should be passed outside of
>   parentheses whenever possible.

@see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#lambda-formatting

That's why IntelliJ shows warning. You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and IntelliJ should show correct solution, or just move lambda out of parentheses. And if lambda is only argument remove parentheses also.

When lambda have to be in parentheses? Only when it is not last parameter in function.

Comment: What if it takes two or more lambdas? And, why SHOULD "be passed outside of parentheses whenever possible"?

Comment: If two lambdas are required, we need to pass them as standard parameters (except the last one). About the second question - for most of the developers, the third version is the cleanest one and gives the best possible readability. And, if we would like to follow Kotlin's guideline we actually don't have a choice :)

Answer (score 5):

As for your immediate problem, you just have to write it like this:

```
profile.sortedWith(Comparator { profile1, profile2 ->
            if (profile1.age > profile2.age) return@Comparator 1
            if (profile1.age < profile2.age) return@Comparator -1
            return@Comparator 0
        }
)
```

However, the code still has several layers of unneeded verbosity. Here are some ways to make it both more concise and more readable.

1. Remove the `return` statement:

   ```
   profile.sortedWith(Comparator { profile1, profile2 ->
       if (profile1.age > profile2.age) 1
       else if (profile1.age < profile2.age) -1
       else 0
   })
   ```
2. Use `when` instead of an `if-else` cascade:

   ```
   profile.sortedWith(Comparator { profile1, profile2 ->
       when {
           profile1.age > profile2.age -> 1
           profile1.age < profile2.age -> -1
           else -> 0
       }
   })
   ```
3. use `Int.compareTo`:

   ```
   profile.sortedWith(Comparator { profile1, profile2 ->
       profile1.age.compareTo(profile2.age) 
   }
   ```
4. use `compareBy`:

   ```
   profile.sortedWith(compareBy(Profile::age))
   ```
5. Don't use the general `sortedWith` when all you need is `sortedBy`:

   ```
   profile.sortedBy(Profile::age)
   ```

Comment: or better (I think) `.sortedBy { it.age }`